# Kendo grid events not working with delegates

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a page that may create several grids at any time. I am trying to set a single event handler for all of them by adding a delegate for the `group`or `dataBound`event but it never triggers.

I am trying this

```
$(document).on('dataBound', 'div.k-grid', onGridDataBound);
```

Is it possible to do this without hooking on to each individual grid's settings when it is being created or without having to bind the event per grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you two alternatives:

1. Override the Grid prototype (before creating any Grids) and inject the event handler(s) directly there:

   ```
   function onGridDataBound(e) {
      alert(e.sender.wrapper.attr("id") + " was databound");
   }

   kendo.ui.Grid.fn.options.dataBound = onGridDataBound;
   ```

Here is a full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/remote-data-binding">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>Grid 1</p>
    <div id="grid1"></div>
    
    <p>Grid 2</p>
    <div id="grid2"></div>

    <script>
      
      function onGridDataBound(e) {
        alert(e.sender.wrapper.attr("id") + " was databound");
      }
      
      $(function() {
        
        kendo.ui.Grid.fn.options.dataBound = onGridDataBound;

        var gridOptions = {
          dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
              read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
          },
          height: 200,
          pageable: true,
          columns: [{
            field:"OrderID",
            filterable: false
          }, {
            field: "ShipName",
            title: "Ship Name"
          }, {
            field: "ShipCity",
            title: "Ship City"
          }]
        };

        $("#grid1").kendoGrid(gridOptions);
        $("#grid2").kendoGrid(gridOptions);

      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

2. [Create a custom Kendo UI widget](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/create-custom-kendo-widget) that has the desired event handlers attached initially.

   ```
     (function($) {
       var kendo = window.kendo,
           ui = kendo.ui,
           Grid = ui.Grid

       var MyGrid = Grid.extend({
         init: function(element, options) {

           Grid.fn.init.call(this, element, options);

           this.bind("dataBound", onGridDataBound);

         },

         options: {
           name: "MyGrid"
         }
       });

       ui.plugin(MyGrid);

     })(jQuery);

     function onGridDataBound(e) {
       alert(e.sender.wrapper.attr("id") + " was databound");
     }
   ```

Here is a full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/remote-data-binding">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title>Kendo UI default event handlers via prototype</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>Grid 1</p>
    <div id="grid1"></div>

    <p>Grid 2</p>
    <div id="grid2"></div>

    <script>

      (function($) {
        var kendo = window.kendo,
            ui = kendo.ui,
            Grid = ui.Grid

        var MyGrid = Grid.extend({
          init: function(element, options) {

            Grid.fn.init.call(this, element, options);

            this.bind("dataBound", onGridDataBound);

          },

          options: {
            name: "MyGrid"
          }
        });

        ui.plugin(MyGrid);

      })(jQuery);

      function onGridDataBound(e) {
        alert(e.sender.wrapper.attr("id") + " was databound");
      }

      $(function() {

        var gridOptions = {
          dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
              read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
          },
          height: 200,
          pageable: true,
          columns: [{
            field:"OrderID",
            filterable: false
          }, {
            field: "ShipName",
            title: "Ship Name"
          }, {
            field: "ShipCity",
            title: "Ship City"
          }]
        };

        $("#grid1").kendoMyGrid(gridOptions);
        $("#grid2").kendoMyGrid(gridOptions);

      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ended up doing something completely different and hacky to get this done but I do like the idea of just creating my own widget for the screens that need this behavior. I'm using Durandal with ko so I would need to replace the default Kendo binding but it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up doing something really inefficient to get this done. Since only the default browser events seem to be delegated, I ended up adding a binder for `mousedown` on any of the grid headers. The handler for that would then bind to the `group` event for that grid since then it is guaranteed to be on the page.

```
var boundGrids = [];
function onGridGroup(e) {
    //Grid group code
};

function onGridHeaderClick(e) {
    var grid = $(this).closest('.k-grid').data('kendoGrid');
    if (!grid._attachedGroup) {
        grid._attachedGroup = true;
        boundGrids.push(grid);
        grid.bind('group', onGridGroup);
    }
};

$(document).on('mousedown', '.k-grid th a.k-link', onGridHeaderClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this thread](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-bind-mvc-kendo-grid-databound-event). Only difference is that in your case you got multiple grids. Due that I would do something like:

```
var grids = $('div.k-grid');
grids.each(function(e) {
    var grid = $(this).data('kendoGrid');
    grid.bind("dataBound", function () {
        alert('Databounded');
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to delegate this event for a grid that is not on the page yet. The grids will be created as the user navigates depending on what they click on. This will not work.